# Не работает компонент Input в React из-за useForm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Всем привет! Когда заполняю данные формы, без компонента Input, то всё работает отлично.
Вот пример кода где всё работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но после того как я сделал из input компонент и вставляю его в разметку, то у меня данные формы поля email становятся undefined

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам Input компонент в других местах кода работает нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я предполагаю что это из-за функции register от хука useForm  что я передаю в компонент Input в ref. А как можно её перенести в Input не знаю, простой передачей ref не работает

целый модуль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как у вас useForm и handleSubmit выглядит?

Comment: добавил картинку в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ref нельзя просто так передавать в функциональный компонент, для этого нужно его завернуть в функцию React.forwardRef

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
const Input = React.forwardRef(({ type, id, checked, onChange, name },ref) => {
  return <input 
    type={type} 
    id={id}
    checked={checked}
    onChange={onChange} 
    name={name} 
    ref={ref} />;
});

export default memo(Input);
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, заработало.